# Facebook API posts are not visible from a mobile device?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Rails Facebook app that makes wall posts using the Graph API.  It is working well, except that these posts are not visible from a mobile device.  Why is this?  I'm not looking for a solution as much as I am looking for an explanation.

When making posts from a mobile app, using the same APP_ID and APP_SECRET, these posts are visible on a mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. All I had to do was go into the developer app, and add a URL under "mobile web URL."  Now, they are showing up fine.